# SSRS 2016 Tablix Filter data type mismatch

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

is this a bug in SSRS ?  I have this 2 filters on my Tablix, `#1` works fine but `#2` produce type mismatch error, even It explicitly cast to INT in my code, and I put just 1 (without quotes in the box). Another thing that I don't have a choice to choose type in dropdown for second filter, it's faded unlike first one.
I re-build report each time, those 2 are isolated fields coming from my Dataset.
So problem probably comes how I can select Integer for type in second filter ??
Best. M

I heard that sometime SSRS has issues if you revert you changes, as XML code doesn't react properly.

[image]

**Updated.** IT works with those modifications:
[image]

Comment: Did you **Refresh Fields** after you added the CAST? Have you tried delete the filter and re-adding?

Comment: Yes, I did all type of refreshing, cleaning cache, rebuilding with no errors, I'm finished with editing my XML code (see my updated pic). and I changed name for cast'ed columns, just for the case, to break any relationship with original column

Comment: I assume it's a buggy. Tx again all.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by modifying raw xml. Pros say this is common problem when xml changes don't retracted properly.